# Is there any difference between -cmp +chroma and -cmp chroma?

Tags: ffmpeg

Both notations `-cmp +chroma` and `-cmp chroma` properly works for me. Is there any difference between them?

My current guess is no, because [all `-cmp` arguments can be presented in digits form](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/FFMPEG_An_Intermediate_Guide/cmp) (`-cmp <string or int>`), and `-cmp 14` is equals to `-cmp chroma`. In the same way `+chroma` equals `+14` which is equals to `14` and `chroma`. Is it right assumption?

Answer (score 0):

To me there is no difference between them. The "+" is implicit and only there for separating 2 parameters of the same setting, for instance:

```
-sws_flags accurate_rnd+bitexact
```

No need for a "+" before "accurate".